# Edit Python script in Notepad++ and run it in Python Shell

Tags: python, notepad++

I love Notepad++ to edit my Python code. But I want to run my scripts in Python Shell. How can I do it?

A piece of script:

[image]

Expected result of running script from Notepad++:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

File->Open->Choose File->In navbar, press run or f5

Comment: Not clear. What file should I choose?

Comment: The python file you want to run. I just assumed that was fairly obvious.

Comment: It is already opened. I edit this file in Notepad++ and I want to run it in Python Shell